# Copying columns between tables, fills entire column with the same value

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im trying to copy data from one table to another. They both have integer columns, AIRPORTS_DATA.ADDRESS_ID and AIRPORT_ADDRESS.AIRPORT_ID.
When I do something like

```
UPDATE AIRPORTS_DATA AS AD
SET ADDRESS_ID = AA.AIRPORT_ID
FROM AIRPORTS_DATA
INNER JOIN AIRPORT_ADDRESS AS AA
ON AIRPORTS_DATA.ADDRESS_ID = AA.AIRPORT_ID
WHERE AA.AIRPORT_ID > 0
```

(not sure about WHERE, just trying to copy entire column)
While it does fill the *address_id* column, it fills with first value from *airport_id* column (in my case 2). So I get a column of 2s.
What am I doing wrong?

Edit1:
Bunch of test data:
First table is airports_data, second one is airport_address

| airport_code | airport_name | address_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAQ | Anapa | [null] |
| ABA | Abakan | [null] |

| airport_id | airport_region | airport_city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | def | abc |
| 5 | fre | gere |

Second table is random generated

Comment: Please note what table is which in the question  -- also I don't think you need a where if you want to change the whole table

Comment: You are updating the column that you are doing the join on?

Comment: Yes?I barely understand what am I doing, just learning sql.

Comment: OK, first this query doesn't make any sense. In practice you are trying to do "nothing". Second, this query wouldn't fill anything. You are saying it does, but I don't believe, [null] means null right? Instead supply sample tables and expected result. Here is a sample for your current tables and code:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=21adca19b6b3ae3ad535dc04ad3d8180

Comment: `address_id` starts as `NULL` so `AIRPORTS_DATA.ADDRESS_ID = AA.AIRPORT_ID` means nothing as  `some_val = NULL` will yield `NULL`. This means `AIRPORTS_DATA.ADDRESS_ID` will be filled  by the last value fetched for `AA.AIRPORT_ID` which is obviously is 2. Remember SQL data is by default unordered.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, I don't think this query would fill anything.

Comment: The OP is getting 2 values in the column so it is filling something. I suspect there is more to the data then is being shown.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, rethinking about it, ,maybe you are right and OP was hiding detail from us. There should be at least one matching item to see what you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rethinking on what Adrian Klaver said, maybe now I understand where you were going wrong (the query itself is wrong as a whole but let's assume it was something more meaningful).

```
UPDATE AIRPORTS_DATA AS AD
SET airport_city = AA.airport_city
FROM AIRPORTS_DATA
INNER JOIN AIRPORT_ADDRESS AS AA
ON AIRPORTS_DATA.ADDRESS_ID = AA.AIRPORT_ID
WHERE AA.AIRPORT_ID > 0;
```

If there were at least one matching iten, then the first matching item's information would be used in updating the table. For sampling I added airport_city = AA.airport_city update. It was nonsense trying to update something that you are using for setting the relation anyway.

The correct way of doing that would be:

```
UPDATE AIRPORTS_DATA
SET airport_city = AA.AIRPORT_CITY
FROM AIRPORT_ADDRESS AS AA
WHERE AIRPORTS_DATA.ADDRESS_ID = AA.AIRPORT_ID 
  and AA.AIRPORT_ID > 0;
```

Here is a [DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6f18591248feb62f9681ba7dff790eb6) showing the issue and correct way of doing that.

Comment: Okay, I guess that was dumb of me.
So, if I have two tables, that dont have any matching data, and need to full copy a column from first to second, what would be the best decision?

Comment: @Anihillator, sorry but I couldn't understand. If there isn't any match then what would you copy anyway. Maybe you should ask that as a new question, clearly giving sample data and expected output.

Comment: @Anihillator. You can copy values from one table to another, but without some way of matching the rows between tables it will a useless exercise. There needs to a be column or group of columns that match a row in one table to a row in the other table to make this useful.